# How to use BehaviorSubject value as an argument for a method?

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I'm using a BehaviorSubject to hold a variable (username) that is being shared with other components and it works great on my templates to display the username.  However, I'd like to be able to use the value of my BehaviorSubject in a service where that value (username) is then used as a parameter for a method like this: myMethod(username){ do stuff }.

The problem, it seems, is that the BehaviorSubject value isn't ready when the method is called.  I've tried calling the method in both the constructor and ngOnInIt, and if I log it to console, it shows that at first it is undefined and then eventually it logs with the correct (username) value.  Is it possible to use BehaviorSubject to get a value that you pass as an argument to a method?

In my example, I have an auth.service, which has my BehaviorSubject (not showing the login/auth stuff because it is irrelevant for this example).  That BehaviorSubject is then subscribed to in my newform.component.ts.  I can display the value on the newform template, but that's not what I want to do. 
 What I'm struggling with is subscribing to that BehaviorSubject value in the newform.component and passing it to a method that calls a service that should return an array of locations based on the username.  I need that array of locations to populate a  input on the newform template, that's why I'm trying to call it on ngOnInIt...so I can get the locations for the  input before the user starts filling in the form.

Below is some code:

## auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private accountInfoSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  accountInfoCurrent = this.accountInfoSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  accountInfoChange(accountName: any) {
    this.accountInfoSource.next(accountName)
  }

}
```

## newform.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Locationslist } from '../services/locationslist.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-charge',
  templateUrl: './new-charge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-charge.component.css']
})
export class NewChargeComponent implements OnInit {

  accountName: string;
  locations;

  constructor(protected authService: AuthService, private locations: Locationslist) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLocations();
  }

  getLocations() {
    this.authService.accountInfoCurrent.subscribe(accountInfo => {
      this.accountName = accountInfo.AccountName;
    } );


    this.locations.getUserLocations(this.accountName)  // <===  this.accountName is undefined
      .subscribe(foundset => {
        this.locations = foundset;
       });

  }


}
```

## locationslist.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Valuelists {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, protected authService: AuthService) { }

  getUserLocations(accountname) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let body = '{\"query\": [ { \"AccountName\" : \"=' + accountname + '\"} ] }';
    const findLocations = 'https://my.api';
    let auth = 'Bearer ' + token;

    return this.http.post(findLocations, body, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Authorization', auth)
    })
  }
}
```

I know the locationslist service works if I hardcode the "accountname" into the argument for getUserLocations(accountname).  In fact, the locationservice eventually works with the BehaviorSubject value, but in the console I first see an error with an http response of 500, then I end up getting the location info.  Here again, it just seems like the BehaviorSubject variable shows up late.  Is there a way to pass the BehaviorSubject value as an argument to a method, or is there a better way to accomplish my goals?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and help.  I ended up using route params to send the data from one component to the next.  It was much more straight forward and more likely the "proper" way to pass a "parameter" to another component (hende the name route params!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your input and help. I ended up using route params to send the data from one component to the next. It was much more straight forward and more likely the "proper" way to pass a "parameter" to another component (hence the name route params!).  It's also not asynchronous, so you don't have to "wait" for the BehaviorSubject observable.  It can be loaded directly OnInIt.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

With angular 12 you can add null or undefined!:

```
subjectUser:BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null!);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just need reactive approach in the function itself.

```
name$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("");

function doSomething() {
  this.name$.subscribe(console.log); // Here you have that name
  // You can filter it like (.pipe(filter(name => !!name)) is you don't want undefined value
}

// Your location function would look like this:
function getLocations() {
  this.name$.pipe(switchMap(name => {  // Every time name subject changes, switch to another getUserLocations
    return this.locations.getUserLocations(name)
  }))
  .subscribe(foundset => {
    this.locations = foundset;
   });
}
```

Remove undefined values like in the function above for the `getLocations` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should look at Resolve Guard. The purpose of this is to pre-fetch some data before your components loads. From your problem, it looks like you would need the username in a component first and then do rest of the functionality.

The basic steps to create a resolve guard are

1. Create a service which fetches you the username
2. Create a resolve guard which implements the `resolve` method to return an abservable by calling your service
3. Add the reference of your resolve guard in the route configuration for that component
4. In your component, subscribe to the component data parameter and fetch the username

Note that a component in the route configuration can have multiple resolve guards.

A good example is available at https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-resolve-guard-example

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect these two methods and make that the second one waits for the first one to complete.

You can do that with the `map` operator, just put the second function in the `map` function.

```
 getLocations() {
    this.authService.accountInfoCurrent.pipe(map(() => {
                this.locations.getUserLocations(this.accountName)  
                      .subscribe(foundset => {
                        this.locations = foundset;
                      });
    })).subscribe(accountInfo => {
      this.accountName = accountInfo.AccountName;
    } );
}
```

Comment: That is actually a bad practice to nest subscriptions inside subscriptions. It would be better to chain it with use of switchMap() operator.